# Horizontal space between columns without spanning horizontal line in cmidrule

Tags: tables, tabularx

In the following table, I wish to add a horizontal gap between columns `3,4`.
All the solutions I found involved adding `\hskip 1in` inside the first column brackets (`c{\hskip 1in}`)
Which makes the line above `cccccc` span that extra space

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption, multirow, siunitx}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[t!]
%~\\
% \smallskip
\centering
\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{P{1cm}P{1cm}P{1cm}P{1cm}P{1cm}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{SO(3)\textsubscript{45}/SO(3)\textsubscript{45}}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{SO(3)\textsubscript{45}/SO(3)}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
\textbf{aaaaaa}  &\textbf{bbbbbb}&\textbf{cccccc}
&\textbf{dddddd}&\textbf{eeeeee}

\\
\midrule
a
&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\
 
b
&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\

\noalign{\vskip 2mm}  
  \bottomrule 
  \noalign{\vskip 2mm} 
 
c
&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\
 
d
&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\

e
&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\
 
f
&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\

g
&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\

\noalign{\vskip 2mm}  
  \bottomrule 
  \noalign{\vskip 2mm} 
  
h
&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\
 
 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{.
}
\label{Tab:faustso3}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a dummy column (that is to say an empty column) between the column 3 and the column 4.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{wc{1cm}wc{1cm}wc{1cm}cwc{1cm}wc{1cm}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{SO(3)\textsubscript{45}/SO(3)\textsubscript{45}}&& \multicolumn{2}{c}{SO(3)\textsubscript{45}/SO(3)}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){5-6}
\textbf{a} &\textbf{b}&\textbf{c}&&\textbf{d}&\textbf{e}\\
\midrule
a&0\%&0\%&&0\%&0\%\\
b&0\%&0\%&&0\%&0\%\\
\noalign{\vskip 2mm}  
\bottomrule 
\noalign{\vskip 2mm} 
c&0\%&0\%&&0\%&0\%\\
d&0\%&0\%&&0\%&0\%\\
e&0\%&0\%&&0\%&0\%\\
f&0\%&0\%&&0\%&0\%\\
g&0\%&0\%&&0\%&0\%\\
\noalign{\vskip 2mm}  
\bottomrule 
\noalign{\vskip 2mm} 
h&0\%&0\%&&0\%&0\%\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: what a genius workaround, thanks